# jQuery DataTables iDisplayLength not working. How do I fix this?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, pagination

I'm trying to fetch big amounts of data from a MySQL-database. Therefore I don't want the user to fetch all data at once, cause this could potentially break the DB-server. Yet when I set the jQuery Datatable options, it doesn't seem to be affected by the DisplayLength I set. When I change the amount of items to show, the box and the pagination at the bottom do change, yet the data remains the same.

I've tried to add an invisible field at the and of the columns, which seemed to help in the past. For this problem it didn't though.

```php
$.post("index.php?action=getDataStructurePropsFromSensorId", {
                sensorId        : sensorId
                                                }, function(data) {
                dataProps.push({ "mDataProp": "data_entry_id" });
                data.forEach(function (item, i) {
                    var th = i;

                    $('#data-th-'+th).html(item['struct_property_label']);

                    $('.data-th').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).html() == '') {
                            $(this).hide();
                        } else {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                    });
                    dataProps.push({ "mDataProp": "data_value_"+i.toString(), "bSortable": false,"bSearchable": false});
                });
                dataProps.push({ "mDataProp": "data_entry_created_at", "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false });
                dataProps.push({ "mDataProp": "data_entry_id", "bVisible": false });

                var obj2 = {
                "bStateSave": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "index.php?&action=getSensorData&sensor_id="+sensorId+"&from="+from+"&till="+till,
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200]],
                "aoColumns": dataProps,
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                return nRow;
                },
                "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']],
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
                },
                "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                }
            };

            oDataTableOverview = $('#sensor_data_dt').dataTable(obj2);
            }, "json");
```

I'm expecting 5 records, depending on the page and the selection in the pagination amount box. Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting all data instead of 5 records?

Comment: Were you able to retrieve only 5 records when you try to request manually with iDisplayLength=5?

Comment: `pageLength` option does not affect the amount of data being *loaded* by any means, it sets the number of records *displayed* per page. If you attempt to decrease the load onto both server and client for big amount of data, it's [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) you've been after.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov as you can see in the code, "bServerSide" is set to true. This, in combination with the "sAjaxSource", should configure DataTables to use server-side processing. "iDisplayLength" should set the amount of records the server returns. Yet this seems to be ignored as I get all records.

Comment: As being said, `pageLength` has [nothing](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength#Description) to do, whatsoever with the size of the data chunk to be loaded. If you already use server-side processing, you should try to manipulate `length` property from within [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option, instead.

Comment: I tried to do that later on, but it didn't seem to work either. I did manage to get this working in the end. I just manually fetched the iDisplayLength and iDisplayStart from the input data and used it in querying the data. This functionality is something that DataTables should handle by itself. I still do not understand why it doesn't in my case, but I'm glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Which datatables version are you using? For datatables with version 1.10 and above, please use the "pageLength" instead of "iDisplayLength"

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 5
} );
```

Comment: I'm using datatables version 1.10.9. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. The thing is that this does work with my other tables.

Answer (score 0):

In My case i fix it

```
datatable_object.settings()[0]._iDisplayLength = -1;
datatable_object.draw();
```